# TypeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run a Python project for OMR, but I am getting an error that I can't possibly know what's wrong. The thing is I'm kind of new on Python development and I'm really confused. I googled for the error but got no answers, therefore I would really appreciate some help. Please see the code and the error message.

I'm running thins on a Ubuntu and Python 2.7.3

Error

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omr# omrcmd.py /media/sf_OMR/test_data/ -f 882E
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/omrcmd.py", line 35, in <module>
    Main(**vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omr/exam_group.py", line 21, in Main
    fimg, fchoice, fout = process_exam_group(frontdir, form, 'front', pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omr/exam_group.py", line 45, in process_exam_group
    wd = Path(testdir)['OMR']
TypeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Code

```
def process_exam_group(testdir, formstr, side, pool=None):
    wd = Path(testdir)['OMR']
    rmtree(str(wd), True)
    [wd[p].mkdir() for p in ['', 'validation', 'names']]
    images = sorted(wd.parent().glob('*.jpg'), key=_NUMSORT)
    if not images:
        raise StandardError('at least one image is required')
    func = partial(process_exam, formcfg=FORMS[formstr][side])
    if pool:
        choices = pool.map(func, images)
    else:
        choices = map(func, images)
    return images, vstack(choices), wd
```

Thank you very very much =D

Comment: What do you think this does: `Path(testdir)['OMR']`, and why do you think it? (That is, what documentation did you read that suggested that it does what you think it does.)

Comment: This is part of the code that is not made by me. I think it is supposed to open the testdir/OMR directory (creating it if doesn't exists)

Comment: OMR stands for "Optical Mark Recognition", automatic reading of tests answersheets @Robᵩ